# How to use greater than and less than or equal in django filter query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to filter data where added in between from date and to date.
but i'm getting **Cannot resolve keyword 'date_gte' into field.**

How can i resolve this issue?

```
    from1 = request.POST.get('from')
    to = request.POST.get('to')
    result = qwerty.objects.filter(date_gte= from1, date_lte= to)
    print(result)
    result.save()
```

Comment: just double the underscores

Comment: @PRMoureu my bad i did not noticed thanks a lot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use *two* consecutive underscores (`__`) to use a lookup:

```
from1 = request.POST.get('from')
to = request.POST.get('to')
result = qwerty.objects.filter(date__gte=from1, date__lte=to)
print(result)
result.save()
```

In this case, you can make use of the [**`__range`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
from1 = request.POST.get('from')
to = request.POST.get('to')
result = qwerty.objects.filter(date__range=(from1, to))
print(result)
result.save()
```