# how to get price range with django?

Tags: python, django

i have price model

```
class Product(models.Model):
  price = models.IntegerField
  membership_discount = models.DecimalField
```

if i get price parameter, (ex. min_price = 100000, max_price = 500000)

I want to get the products multiplied by the price fields and membership_discount fields.

not this

```
Product.objects.filter(price__range = (min_price, max_price))
```

i want

```
Product.objects.filter(price * (1+membership_discount)__range = (min_price, max_price))
```

Comment: Look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922849/how-to-use-greater-than-and-less-than-or-equal-in-django-filter-query

Answer (score 1):

`lte` = less than or equal to

`gte` = greater than or equal to

this is documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt

```
max_price = #max price logic here
min_price = #min price logic her

#this will filter all products (price <= max_price and price >= min_price)  
Product.objects.filter(price__lte = max_price, price__gte = min_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use annotations for the QuerySet and apply the filter on the annotation.

```py
Product.objects.annotate(
    member_price=F('price') * (1 + F('membership_discount'))
).filter(
    member_price__range=(min_price, max_price)
)
```

If the `price`field and the `membership_dicsount` do not have the same type, you might need to make usage of the `ExpressionWrapper` with a specific `output_field`

```py
Product.objects.annotate(
    member_price=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('price') * (1 + F('membership_discount')),
        output_field=DecimalField()
    )
).filter(
    member_price__range=(min_price, max_price)
)
```

Docs:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations